# Python Django + postgresSQGl problem with login function

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a problem with authenticate login.

My code:

```
class UsersPass(models.Model):
    id_user = models.IntegerField(null=False,primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)`
```

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print('haslo',password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('main_view')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Account not active or invalid login details")
    else:
        return render(request, 'main.html', {})`
```

urls.py

```
     path("",views.index,name='index'),
      path("main/",views.main_view, name='main_view'),
        path('login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
```

Password and login are correct get from database. Print showing correct password. I don't have warning in console, but login function is not working. Every time login ending incorrect with message "Account not active or invalid login details".

What is the problem here?

I checked the connection to the database many times, changed passwords and logins, regardless of whether I entered the correct data or not, I could not log in.

/edit

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import psycopg2

class UsersPass(models.Model):
    id_user = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.username} - {self.password}'

    class Calendar(models.Model):
    date_plan = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True)
    priority = models.BooleanField(default=False)


     class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = 
    models.CharField(max_length=200,default='123456789')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} - {self.name}'`

     setting.py 

       
     

        `from pathlib import Path
    import os
    
    
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
    STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    
    
    
    # Application definition
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'Application',
        'bootstrap5',
    ]
    
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'Insurance.urls'
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    
      WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Insurance.wsgi.application'
    
    
    
    
         DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
           'NAME': 'myApp',
           'USER': 'postgres',
           'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
           'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
           'PORT': '5432',
       }
    }
    
    
    
    
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 
       
       
       
       
       
     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
          },
            ]
    
    
    
         LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    
         TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    
         USE_I18N = True
    
         USE_TZ = True
    
    
    
    
          STATIC_URL = 'static/'
          STATICFILES_DIRS = [
          STATIC_DIR,
          ]
    
    
    
      DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'``
```

Comment: If the password is correct, what have you learned from debugging the `authenticate()` call? Is `user` not being defined? Assuming you're using the method provided by `ModelBackend`, it expects you to pass a request to it as well as username and password. https://github.com/django/django/blob/fc62e17778dad9eab9e507d90d85a33d415f64a7/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L36

Comment: Are u using custom user model. is yes, have you updated in settings.py. Please share your settings.py and models.py for more information.

Comment: add setting,py and models.py

Comment: I tried to edit your code, but your indentation is all messed up. Please [edit] your question and fix it; it should at least compile.

Answer (score 1):

If the password and username are correct as you say, **the problem is that the account is not active**

***User*** model has a field called **is_active**:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(
_("active"),
default=True,
help_text=_(
    "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
    "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
),
```

the best way of resolving this is to access the User model data through **Django shell** and if "**is_active**" for this specific user is False set it to True and it should work